# Angular how to count numbers of array in array

Tags: angular

In angular app i need to show the number of arrays which are in arrays.

Example

```
 {
            "city_name": "LAHORE",
            "family_members": [
                {
                    "user_id": "IGT\/D\/PHI3\/0000000002\/0118\/003-11128",
                    "gender": "F",
                    "name": "IREM NILGUN",
                    "age": "34",
                    "relationship": "Wife"
                },
                {
                    "user_id": "IGT\/D\/PHI3\/0000000002\/0118\/003-11129",
                    "gender": "F",
                    "name": "DEFNE ALINA",
                    "age": "4",
                    "relationship": "Daughter"
                },
                {
                    "user_id": "IGT\/D\/PHI3\/0000000002\/0118\/003-11130",
                    "gender": "M",
                    "name": "OMER KARAN",
                    "age": "1",
                    "relationship": "Son"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "city_name": "LAHORE",
            "family_members": [
                {
                    "user_id": "IGT\/D\/PHI3\/0000000002\/0118\/003-5933",
                    "gender": "F",
                    "name": "RAFIA SAQIB",
                    "age": "2",
                    "relationship": "Daughter"
                },
                {
                    "user_id": "IGT\/D\/PHI3\/0000000002\/0118\/003-5934",
                    "gender": "M",
                    "name": "MUHAMMAD MAAZ",
                    "age": "10",
                    "relationship": "Son"
                },
                {
                    "user_id": "IGT\/D\/PHI3\/0000000002\/0118\/003-5935",
                    "gender": "F",
                    "name": "GULZAREEN SAQIB",
                    "age": "29",
                    "relationship": "Wife"
                },
                {
                    "user_id": "IGT\/D\/PHI3\/0000000002\/0118\/003-5936",
                    "gender": "M",
                    "name": "MUSAB SAQIB",
                    "age": "8",
                    "relationship": "Son"
                }
            ]
        }
```

As there are 2 arrays and in array there is array of family member.
In first array i have 3 family members and in 2 array i have 4 family members.

I need to count only the family members of array. like the result will be 7 in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const data = [{ "city_name": "LAHORE", "family_members": [ { "user_id": "IGT\/D\/PHI3\/0000000002\/0118\/003-11128", "gender": "F", "name": "IREM NILGUN", "age": "34", "relationship": "Wife" }, { "user_id": "IGT\/D\/PHI3\/0000000002\/0118\/003-11129", "gender": "F", "name": "DEFNE ALINA", "age": "4", "relationship": "Daughter" }, { "user_id": "IGT\/D\/PHI3\/0000000002\/0118\/003-11130", "gender": "M", "name": "OMER KARAN", "age": "1", "relationship": "Son" } ] }, { "city_name": "LAHORE", "family_members": [ { "user_id": "IGT\/D\/PHI3\/0000000002\/0118\/003-5933", "gender": "F", "name": "RAFIA SAQIB", "age": "2", "relationship": "Daughter" }, { "user_id": "IGT\/D\/PHI3\/0000000002\/0118\/003-5934", "gender": "M", "name": "MUHAMMAD MAAZ", "age": "10", "relationship": "Son" }, { "user_id": "IGT\/D\/PHI3\/0000000002\/0118\/003-5935", "gender": "F", "name": "GULZAREEN SAQIB", "age": "29", "relationship": "Wife" }, { "user_id": "IGT\/D\/PHI3\/0000000002\/0118\/003-5936", "gender": "M", "name": "MUSAB SAQIB", "age": "8", "relationship": "Son" } ] }]
        
const result  =  data.map(res=>res.family_members.length).reduce((acc,ele)=>acc+ele,0);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let memberCount = 0;
const familyObj = {
            "city_name": "LAHORE",
            "family_members": [
                {
                    "user_id": "IGT\/D\/PHI3\/0000000002\/0118\/003-11128",
                    "gender": "F",
                    "name": "IREM NILGUN",
                    "age": "34",
                    "relationship": "Wife"
                },
                {
                    "user_id": "IGT\/D\/PHI3\/0000000002\/0118\/003-11129",
                    "gender": "F",
                    "name": "DEFNE ALINA",
                    "age": "4",
                    "relationship": "Daughter"
                },
                {
                    "user_id": "IGT\/D\/PHI3\/0000000002\/0118\/003-11130",
                    "gender": "M",
                    "name": "OMER KARAN",
                    "age": "1",
                    "relationship": "Son"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "city_name": "LAHORE",
            "family_members": [
                {
                    "user_id": "IGT\/D\/PHI3\/0000000002\/0118\/003-5933",
                    "gender": "F",
                    "name": "RAFIA SAQIB",
                    "age": "2",
                    "relationship": "Daughter"
                },
                {
                    "user_id": "IGT\/D\/PHI3\/0000000002\/0118\/003-5934",
                    "gender": "M",
                    "name": "MUHAMMAD MAAZ",
                    "age": "10",
                    "relationship": "Son"
                },
                {
                    "user_id": "IGT\/D\/PHI3\/0000000002\/0118\/003-5935",
                    "gender": "F",
                    "name": "GULZAREEN SAQIB",
                    "age": "29",
                    "relationship": "Wife"
                },
                {
                    "user_id": "IGT\/D\/PHI3\/0000000002\/0118\/003-5936",
                    "gender": "M",
                    "name": "MUSAB SAQIB",
                    "age": "8",
                    "relationship": "Son"
                }
            ]
        }


for (let family in familyObj) {
 if (familyObj[familyObj].family_members && familyObj[familyObj].family_members.length) {
  memberCount += familyObj[familyObj].family_members.length;
 }
}
```

Please try this code.

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the question.

It can be done like this -

```
const data = [{ "city_name": "LAHORE", "family_members": [ { "user_id": "IGT\/D\/PHI3\/0000000002\/0118\/003-11128", "gender": "F", "name": "IREM NILGUN", "age": "34", "relationship": "Wife" }, { "user_id": "IGT\/D\/PHI3\/0000000002\/0118\/003-11129", "gender": "F", "name": "DEFNE ALINA", "age": "4", "relationship": "Daughter" }, { "user_id": "IGT\/D\/PHI3\/0000000002\/0118\/003-11130", "gender": "M", "name": "OMER KARAN", "age": "1", "relationship": "Son" } ] }, { "city_name": "LAHORE", "family_members": [ { "user_id": "IGT\/D\/PHI3\/0000000002\/0118\/003-5933", "gender": "F", "name": "RAFIA SAQIB", "age": "2", "relationship": "Daughter" }, { "user_id": "IGT\/D\/PHI3\/0000000002\/0118\/003-5934", "gender": "M", "name": "MUHAMMAD MAAZ", "age": "10", "relationship": "Son" }, { "user_id": "IGT\/D\/PHI3\/0000000002\/0118\/003-5935", "gender": "F", "name": "GULZAREEN SAQIB", "age": "29", "relationship": "Wife" }, { "user_id": "IGT\/D\/PHI3\/0000000002\/0118\/003-5936", "gender": "M", "name": "MUSAB SAQIB", "age": "8", "relationship": "Son" } ] }]

const sum = 0;

arrayName.forEach(value => {
sum = sum+value.family_members.length;
console.log(sum);});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your data structure is an array of objects like

{city_name: string, family_members: Array}

```
//First map every element to get an array of "family_members" arrays
const totalLength = data
  .map(item => item.family_members || []) // || [] prevents errors when "family_members" is not defined
//Now sum the lengths of all the mapped "family_members" arrays
  .reduce((tot, members) => tot + members.length, 0);
```