# Problem with displaying array length correctly

Tags: html, arrays, angular

In an Angular project, I want to loop through **filterLifePolicies** array because I want to pass via URI the `LobDsc` property.

The problem is that I also want to output as a number the length of the array but because I loop through each element if the array contains e.g.
3 objects, 3 cards are displayed...I only want one card with the number 3 (array length).

HTML:

```html
<div class="card" *ngFor="let policy of filterLifePolicies">
    <a [routerLink]= "['/contracts', policy.LobDsc]"
      routerLinkActive="active" class="noLinksDecoration">
    <div class="card-body text-center">
      <img src="../../assets/images/Component62_1.svg"> 
      <p class="policyTitle">Ζωή & Υγεία</p>
      <p class="counter">{{countLife}}</p>
    </div>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Part of Typescript:

```javascript
getCustomerPolicies () {

    this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:8080/o/mye/pol').subscribe({
    next: res => {  

    this.filterLifePolicies = res.Life.Policies;
    console.debug(this.filterLifePolicies);
    this.countLife = this.filterLifePolicies.length;
```

Comment: It's Angular 11

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57037960/angular-how-to-count-numbers-of-array-in-array) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048734/how-to-get-length-of-array-in-template-syntax) help?

Comment: Hmm..I don't think so..the problem is how to combine the *ngFor I need with the correct array length output

Comment: @AndreasV Please help me understand your question better. So, let's say the length of `filterLifePolicies` is 3, thus the value of `countLife` is 3. Now since you are iterating using `ngFor` directive, you'll be seeing three cards. But since `countLife` value is static, you see three cards but in all of the cards, the value of `countLife` is same, which is 3, which is what you don't want? Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you are 90% correct. The only thing you are missing is that I don't want to see 3 cards with the value of countLife which is 3 but one card with the value 3!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following, considering `countLife` variable is assigned the required value.

```html
<div class="card">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let policy of filterLifePolicies; index as i">
    <a *ngIf="i < 1" [routerLink]="['/contracts', policy.LobDsc]" routerLinkActive="active" class="noLinksDecoration">
      <div class="card-body text-center">
        <img src="../../assets/images/Component62_1.svg">
        <p class="policyTitle">Ζωή & Υγεία</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </ng-container>
  <p class="counter">{{countLife}}</p>
</div>
```

In the above code snippet, `ng-container` is being used to iterate through `filterLifePolicies` in order to access `LobDsc` value. Since the iteration should not create duplicate HTML `div` elements with CSS class `card-body`, an additional check via `ngIf` is being used to check the `index` value, such that it should be always lesser than 1.

Although if the `LobDsc` value is the same for all the values of `filterLifePolicies`, the recommended approach would be to fetch its value via the dot notation and store it in a variable that can be later binded directly to your template during runtime.

Comment: Thanks for your respone! Although the countLife appeared only once, the other content of the card which is the image and the title appeared again 3 times

Comment: Oh okay. So is it required for the `card-body` to be wrapped within the anchor tag?

Comment: Yes...that's the case

Comment: Okay, but what if there are multiple `LobDsc` properties in the `filterLifePolicies` object? Should the individual values of `LobDsc` be concatenated to the `routerLink` property on each iteration?

Comment: LobDsc is always the same for all LifePolicies...so that's not a problem. The workaround I found based on that is the following: ```<div class="card" *ngFor="let policy of filterLifePolicies | slice:0:1;">``` so, only one item is returned at the iteration...at the same time I have the LobDsc I need to pass in url...But I wonder if it is too hakcy

Comment: The `SlicePipe` is impure. So, you can definitely use it. Though it's bad practice to use functions or getters inside of templates (as long as you're not following the OnPush change detection strategy), the better way would be to put the logic for slicing the array inside the component's controller.